# PHP pasword_verify always saying password is valid except if column is empty

Tags: php, html, mysql, password-hash

I'm not 100% sure I'm using PHP password verify correctly as it always says the the password entered from the form is valid. The part of my code I believe is having problems:

```
include('../connection/conn.php');
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($db_email, $db_password);
            $count = $stmt->num_rows;
            //password hasing
            if ($count == 1)
            {
                while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                    if (password_verify($password, $db_password))
                    {
                        echo "Sucess";
                    }
            }
            }
```

I'll add int the conn.php file contents just in case anyone needs it

```
    <?php 
global $conn;
$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "loginV2";
$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $db);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
else
{

    echo "<p id='connection'>True</p>";
}

?>
```

Regardless of what password I entered into the form, "Success" is echo'd to the page of whether the correct password is entered. Here is the html form:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) ?>" method="post"  name="input_form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
                <label>Email:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="email">
                <p class="error" id="email_Err"><?php echo $emailErr ?></p>
                <label>Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password">
                <p class="error" id="password_Err"><?php echo $passwordErr ?></p>
                <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
            </form>
```

My error is probably stupid but I've tried to learn password_verify and password_hash from the PHP manual and as far as I can tell, this code should work. Even if it's not well written, should function. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:

All this code apart from my mqysli_connect is within one PHP file "login.php". I'll insert the entirety of the code below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            function validateForm()
            {
                var email = document.forms["input_form"]["email"].value;
                var password = document.forms["input_form"]["password"].value;
                var valid = true;
                if (email == null || email == "")
                    {
                        document.getElementById("email_Err").innerHTML = "Email is a required field";
                        valid = false;
                    }
                if (password == null || password == "")
                    {
                        document.getElementById("password_Err").innerHTML = "Password is a required field";
                        valid = false;
                    }

                if (valid === false)
                    {
                        $(function()
                         {
                            $( ".form_container" ).effect("shake");
                        });
                    }
                return valid;
            }

            $(function()
            {
                $('.form_container').hide().slideDown('slow');
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <?php 

        $email = $password = "";
        $emailErr = $passwordErr = "";
        $otherErr = "";
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
        {
            $dataErr = false;
            if (empty($_POST["email"]))
            {
                $emailErr = "Email is a required field";
                $dataErr = true;
            }
            else
            {
                $email = input($_POST["email"]);
                if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                    $emailErr = "Invalid email "; 
                    $dataErr = true;
                }
            }

            if (empty($_POST["password"]))
            {
                $passwordErr = "Password is a required field";
                $dataErr = true;
            }
            else
            {
                $password = $_POST["password"];
                if (strlen($password) < 8)
                {
                    $passwordErr = "Invalid Entry";
                    $dataErr = true;
                }
            }


           //Suspected problem here 

        if (!$dataErr)
        {
            include('../connection/conn.php');
            //Duplicate Check
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($db_email, $db_password);
            $count = $stmt->num_rows;
            //password hasing
            if ($count == 1)
            {
                while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                    if (password_verify($password, $db_password))
                    {
                        echo "Sucess";
                    }
            }
            }
        }   
        }

        function input($data) 
        {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;
        }






        ?>
        <div class="form_container">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <!--  -->
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) ?>" method="post"  name="input_form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
                <label>Email:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="email">
                <p class="error" id="email_Err"><?php echo $emailErr ?></p>
                <label>Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password">
                <p class="error" id="password_Err"><?php echo $passwordErr ?></p>
                <input type="submit" value="Login">
            </form>
            <?php echo "<p style='text-align: center; color: red;'> " . $otherErr . "</p>" ?>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks again

Comment: It looks like you're missing some code that would be necessary for us to determine what's going wrong with this.

Comment: Where do `$password` and `$db_password` come from, for example?

Comment: $db_password come from mysqli::bind_result(). But, they are using SELECT *. Maybe second field doesn't have the password itself

Comment: When storing your database passwords, are you using the `password_hash` function?

Comment: Hiya, sorry for the confusion. I'll edit the question now with all the necessary code

Comment: @Mr.Meeseeks yes I am. I've added the rest of my code now to the question

Comment: Is the column where you're storing the hashed password at least 60 characters wide?

Comment: Yeahh I have. I was originally using binary(60) but to be sure I've tried VARCHAT(255) and the problem is still happening

Comment: If you've changed the column after storing results, you might need to re-store those results because they might've been truncated. I would also check to see if `$db_password` is actually the proper hashed password.

Comment: @Mr.Meeseeks yeah, I have a sign up page so I dropped the database and re-created it with different variable types and then registered again so that the the table was populated and still the same problem. It always echo success. I did the same thing with the other variables I tried.

Comment: @Mr.Meeseeks I tried echo the $db_password and the output matches the MySQL console. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah, just to make sure `bind_result` is grabbing the right value.

Comment: I tried again to echo `$db_password` and nothing is outputted. Any suggestions?

Comment: `$db_email` also does not output. So I assume `bind_result` isn't fetching the data correctly

Comment: What are the names of your email and password columns in the database table? Try `SELECT email_field, password_field` in your sql query with the proper column names.

Comment: The fields within my table are just called email and password (within back quotes of course). I changed my query, to select the specific columns. Still no change

Comment: The query must be returning some results as `$count` within the if statement must be 1 in order for the echo success to be executed.

Comment: Can you try placing `store_result` after `bind_result` and see if you get values for `$db_email` and `$db_password`?

Comment: That sounded like the perfect solution but unfortunately, still no change :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. 6hrs of var_dumps and the problem was in conn.php

```
include('../connection/conn.php');
            //Duplicate Check
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT email, password FROM users WHERE email=?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($db_email, $db_password);
            $stmt->fetch();
```

Just before the password is verified the password we include conn.php to connect to the database. This is includes my database password is has the variable name as the user input password:

```
    <?php 
    global $conn;
    $server = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
// $password is set to nothing
    $password = "";
    $db = "loginV2";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $db);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
    else
    {

        echo "<p id='connection'>True</p>";
    }

    ?>
```

This meant that when password_verify was executed it was comparing $password from conn.php, which is blank. Changing the variables to connect to database resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested some stuff on my own database and found that the following is working for my database table:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(...blah blah blah);
$email = "my_email_here";

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT email, password FROM my_table_here WHERE email=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($one, $two);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    var_dump($one); // my email from database
    var_dump($two); // my hashed password from database (looks something like $2y$10$VmfW7/b1t4SVxi7wlxjZmu8...)
}
```

Not sure what the difference would be here except the sql query from your question.

---

EDIT

Something you could try is:

```
$password = 'testing';
$hashed = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

if (password_verify($password, $hashed) {
    echo "password verified";
} else {
    echo "not verified";
}
```

Replace your `while` statement with the above code and see what gets echoed

Comment: I re-wrote the code based off of yours and var_dump and echo both output the hashed password correctly. However, success is still echo'd if i enter the wrong password. Very frustrated now, not sure if there is a minor problem or the way I write my `password_verify` function is just incorrect.

Comment: `password_verify` is being used correctly, it just has to have the proper values. Are you using `password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)` or something similar to generate your passwords?

Comment: My hashed password looks something like `$2y$10$VmfW7/b1t4SVxi7wlxjZmu...`

Comment: The hash I'm using is `$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` the hashing of the password and the verification of the password occur on different page. Just wondering if that makes any different. I didn't think it did but I'm still new to `password_verify`

Comment: My hash looks something like this: `$2y$10$9l.vF8zoceUTjqBnrM419.gS8mMsHRXmD6w.5PDvT9c`

Comment: Can you show me what `var_dump(password_verify($password, $db_password));` returns?

Comment: When i enter the correct password: `C:\wamp64\www\loginV2\login.php:96:boolean true` and when i enter random characters the same. So `password_verify` always returns true

Comment: Just as a side note: using `password_verify` has to have the plaintext password as the first argument and the hashed password as the second argument, eg: `password_verify('users_password123', '$2y$10$9l.vF8zoceUTjqBn...')`

Comment: When faced with this sort of issue, I usually drop in some debugging.  For example, the line before your password_verify() call, I'd display the values for both variables.  Ensure that the data going into the function is what you think it is.  If not, work backwards to find the error.  Good luck!

Comment: At this point I've tried copying the hashed password into the password_verify so that it looks like this: `password_verify($password, '$2y$10$goMP/hmgfWjj5DO.STrdLO.gFp/BelS.nnFObzmje7WKd9JSPL9lW')` and the var_dump of password_verify still returns true regardless of teh password. Completely stuck on this one. The only time the var_dump returns false is when I enter in plain text instead of the $password

Comment: Then there's most likely something wrong with `$password`